# Let $h(x) = 6x\sin(x)\cos(x)$. How can I find $h^{\prime}(\pi/2)$?

Tags: calculus

I honestly don't even know where to start... Product rule? How would I apply the product rule? Every time I try and solve it I get $0$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: $$2sin(x)cos(x)=sin(2x)$$

Comment: Can you show how you apply the product rule? I think you make some simple math error.

Comment: Note: whenever you need to take the derivative of three functions multiplied together, the product rule looks like this: $(fgh)' = f'gh + fg'h + fgh'$

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can solve this is via product rule. However, you can simplify the problem to a product of two functions using a trig identity (Method A) or you can keep it as a product of three functions (Method B).

`Method A`

$h(x)=6x\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Using $2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$, we can turn this three function product into a two function product.

$h(x) = 3x\sin(2x)$

Product rule for two functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ is $(u\cdot v)' = u'\cdot v+v'\cdot u$.

$h'(x) = 3\cdot(x\sin(2x))' = 3 \cdot (\sin(2x) + 2x\cos(2x))$

`Note that for the derivative of sin(2x), we had to use chain rule.`

We can now plug in $\frac\pi2$ and find the derivative.

$h'(\frac\pi2) = 3 \cdot (\sin(\pi) + 2(\frac\pi2)\cos(\pi)) = 3 \cdot (0-\pi) = -3\pi$
$$$$
`Method B`

$h(x)=6x\sin(x)\cos(x)$

The product rule for three functions $u$, $v$, and $w$ is $(uvw)' = (u')vw + u(v')w + uv(w')$. This can be easily derived from the product rule for two functions. Just let one of the functions, be a product of a different two!

$h'(x) = 6\cdot (x \cdot \sin(x) \cdot \cos(x))' = 6\cdot (\sin(x)\cos(x) + x\cdot\cos^2(x)-x\cdot\sin^2(x))$.

Plug and chug! $h'(\frac\pi2) = 6 \cdot (0+0-\frac\pi2) = -3\pi$

Answer (score 1):

You don't get zero:  $h'(x)=6\sin x \cos x+6x(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)\implies h'(\frac{\pi}2)=-3\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you apply the product rule.  Put some parentheses in so you have a product of two functions.  You will get something that involves the product of two other functions. 
 $(abc)'=((ab)c)'=(ab)'c+(ab)c'=a'bc+ab'c+abc'$.  What is wrong with getting $h'(\frac \pi 2)=0?$